# Select product id from product genre table but show by exect macting

Tags: php, mysql

This can be question which can ask on this site but I unable to find answer for it.

My question is that I have 3 tables

a . Product table

b.  category table

c.  product_category table

Any product can have multiple categories

So if i want to know all products which contain any category so i can use mysql query like

```
Select * 
From products 
   left join product_category on (product.id = product_category.product_id)  
Where category id in (45,56,78)
```

but if I want all only those products which have all these categories then how i find it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.id
from products p
join product_category pc on p.id = pc.product_id
where category_id in (45,56,78)
group by p.id
having count(distinct category_id) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks , I am checking it, I will report you. Between when there are lot of records in tables then this query can take much time ?

Comment: It should run very fast since it only depends on the key columns